# Analog multiplier in lab

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog

I designed in Pspice an analog multiplier made of op amps and everything worked as planned.
Today i was in the lab and assembled the circuit. When I tried to put sinus waves at both inputs, I got distorted sinus wave at the output. I tried to raise one of the inputs' phase and found out that putting phase shift of 135 degrees fixes the output.
Does anyone know why it happens?
The circuit:
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What did you do to introduce a phase shift?

Comment: One of the inputs' phase was 0 and I raised the seconds' phase to 135 degrees  (using the signal generator).

Comment: Not sure but it might be the LM324's primitive output stage. Try adding bias resistors from the affected op-amp outputs to Vee (possibly including intermediate stage op-amps too, do check). Or change to a more recent op-amp